# Using String.replace in a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, str-replace

```
for (var z = 0; z < spells[0].vars.length; z++) {
    if (spells[0].sanitizedTooltip.indexOf(spells[0].vars[z].key) > -1) {
        var key = spells[0].vars[z].key;
        sanitizedOut = spells[0].sanitizedTooltip.replace("{{ " + key + " }}", spells[0].vars[z].coeff);
    }
}
```

This piece of code is meant to replace multiple "keys" in a string. However, only the last occurrence is being replaced.

> Throws a dagger dealing {{ e2 }} (+{{ a1 }}) magic damage. The dagger
>   bounces to the 4 closest enemies dealing 10% less damage with each
>   bounce. Enemies hit are marked for 4 seconds. Katarina's basic attacks
>   or spells will consume the mark dealing {{ e3 }} (+{{ a2 }})
>   additional magic damage.

This is `sanitizedTooltip`. `spells[0].vars` is:

`[ { key: 'a1', link: 'spelldamage', coeff: [ 0.45 ] },
  { key: 'a2', link: 'spelldamage', coeff: [ 0.15 ] } ]`

However, the result of this for loop only returns:

> Throws a dagger dealing {{ e2 }} (+{{ a1 }}) magic damage. The dagger
>   bounces to the 4 closest enemies dealing 10% less damage with each
>   bounce. Enemies hit are marked for 4 seconds. Katarina's basic attacks
>   or spells will consume the mark dealing {{ e3 }} (+0.15) additional
>   magic damage.

...where {{ a1 }} is expected to be +0.45 instead. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Uh, you're throwing away all `sanitizedOut` variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each iteration of the loop is operating on the original `spells[0].sanitizedTooltip`. Each time through, `sanitizedOut` gets re-assigned with the result of the latest iteration, so when the loop exits you only see the last result.

Answer (score 0):

To help you replacing all occurrences in a single call, you can build a recursive function, like this:

```
function replaceAll(value, oldChar, newChar) {
   if (value.indexOf(oldChar) > -1) {
      value = value.replace(oldChar, newChar);
      return replaceAll(value, oldChar, newChar);
   } else {
      return value;
   }
}

var s = "A B A B A B A B";
s = replaceAll(s, "A" , "X");
alert(s);
```

The result will be: `X B X B X B X B`